# Too much padding in the add a comment box

Tags: bug, design, css

There seems to be quite a bit of unneeded padding in the comment box.

[image]

I'm thinking about half the current padding would look better.

Comment: I posted this because everytime i start to comment I stop and check the start of the comment because it feels like i have extra space there.